# How to find information about a Debian package removed from the Debian repository?

Tags: debian, package-management

There are many times a package is removed form the Debian repo. For a brief time, you can find the reason which generated the removal of a package.

But after brief period of time, that info. is lost. Is there a way to search and get info. on removals, say last 6 months or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removals are logged a year at a time on ftp-master, *e.g.* https://ftp-master.debian.org/removals-2016.txt for 2016.

The current year is logged in https://ftp-master.debian.org/removals.txt. The logs give the removal bug number which will detail the reason.

The full list is available at https://ftp-master.debian.org/removals-full.txt (70 MiB large as of January 2024).

Additional information:

- https://ftp-master.debian.org/#removed
- https://wiki.debian.org/ftpmaster_Removals